# How to update dependency property on change in adaptive trigger?

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a dependency property on my page. I want to update it whenever Adaptive Trigger MinWindowWidth changes.

I have tried this but it does not recognize AdaptiveValue(dependency property),

> The TargetPropertyPath "AdaptiveValue" syntax is not valid.

```
            <VisualState x:Name="desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="AdaptiveValue" Value="1024"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
```

The workaround I am planning to use is to create a collapsed Textbox and set its Text to the value on Adaptive Trigger event. Then subscribe to the textchanged event and get the value.

Is there any decent/recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: Normally this should work... try setting a x:Name inside the <Page> tag and change your State trigger to PageName.AdaptiveValue